# YouTube in FancyBox is too small

Tags: javascript

Clicking the image in the left sidebar at http://vaiman.org/ we have **too small** YouTube box. I need to make YouTube area greater. How?

Here is my JavaScript code (http://vaiman.org/wp-content/themes/vaiman/javascript/youtube.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 1000/*850*/,
        maxHeight   : 1000/*638*/,
        minWidth    : 1000/*850*/,
        minHeight   : 1000/*638*/,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : 1000/*'100%'*/ /*70%*/,
        height      : 1000/*'100%'*/ /*70%*/,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

What is my error?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I click your thumbnail and it opens fancybox in what looks to be a default size youtube player

Comment: Is it the container of the fancy box you need to enlarge?

Answer (score 2):

This code works below you can see an example in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/hphdL/2/)

```
<div id="single_1"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A3Atj57r15U?autoplay=1" class="various fancybox.iframe">
<img src="http://vaiman.org/wp-content/themes/vaiman/images/photo1.jpg" width="191" height="91" alt=""></a></div>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
    });
});​
```